# variable cannot be resolved in Java

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an Android App with Db, Java and OOP.

This is the source of the main activity:

```
public class EpsoftSMSActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final MyDatabase db=new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext());

        db.open();  //apriamo il db

        if (db.listaParametri().getCount()==0)
        {
            setup_parametri();

             /*final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
             dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
             dialog.setTitle("Login");
             dialog.setCancelable(true);
             //there are a lot of settings, for dialog, check them all out!


             //set up button
             Button registra = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.registra);
             registra.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {

                         String username = dialog.findViewById(R.id.username).toString();
                         String password = dialog.findViewById(R.id.password).toString();

                         db.inserimentoParametri(username, password);
                         dialog.dismiss();
                     }
             });

             Button annulla = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.annulla);

             annulla.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                     }
             });

             //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
             dialog.show();*/
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.chiudi:

                finish();
                System.exit(0);
                return true;

            case R.id.setup:

                setup_parametri();
                return true;

            case R.id.info:

                  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                    dialog.setTitle("Informazioni & Credits");
                    dialog.setCancelable(true);
                    //there are a lot of settings, for dialog, check them all out!

                  /*  //set up text
                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                    //text.setText(R.string.lots_of_text);

                    //set up image view
                    ImageView img = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);*/

                    //set up button
                    //set up button
                    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
                    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });
                    //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
                    dialog.show();

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void setup_parametri()
    {
         final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
         dialog.setTitle("Login");
         dialog.setCancelable(true);
         //there are a lot of settings, for dialog, check them all out!


         //set up button
         Button registra = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.registra);
         registra.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {

                     String username = dialog.findViewById(R.id.username).toString();
                     String password = dialog.findViewById(R.id.password).toString();

                      db.inserimentoParametri(username, password);
                     dialog.dismiss();
                 }
         });

         Button annulla = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.annulla);

         annulla.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                 }
         });

         //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it    
         dialog.show();
    }
}
```

In the latest function, called "setup_parametri" I try to call "db.inserimentoParametri", but Eclipse tell me:

> "db cannot be resolved"

Db is defined in the oncreate.

What's up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared db as a variable within `onCreate()` without passing it on to `setup_parametri()`

you need to either make it a class variable:

```
public class EpsoftSMSActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    final MyDatabase db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        db = new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext());



        db.open();  //apriamo il db
```

or change the signature of `setup_parametri()` to `setup_parametri(MyDatabase db)`

Answer (score 2):

`db` is a local variable declared inside `onCreate()`. It is not visible to any other methods. You probably want to make it an instance field of your Activity class, which means it will be available to all methods of the class.

Declare the field outside `onCreate()`, but initialize it inside. Like this:

```
private MyDatabase db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ....

    db = new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: I've tried (in my actually ignorance on OOP) to declare db before the oncreate. Result: none error in compiling but errore in execution.

Comment: i declare it in the same mode before the first @override.

The error is this

06-09 01:27:16.252: E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 01:27:16.252: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:100)

Comment: I think you were trying to call getApplicationContext() before the activity was fully initialized. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

When your OnClickerListener event handler is run, the DB variable isn't in scope.

Move the db definition to outside the scope of the onCreate method, i.e. make it a member variable.

Comment: I've tried (in my actually ignorance on OOP) to declare db before the oncreate. Result: none error in compiling but errore in execution.